# Undefined use of constant i dentro de un for loop

Tags: php

Estoy obteniendo un erro que jamas obtuve antes dentro de un loop for.

Estoy tratando de contar cuantas veces se repite un numero de manera consecutiva.

Este es mi arreglo:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8);
```

Y este es mi código:

```
$cont = 1;
$longest = $cont;
$number = $myArray[0];

for($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++) {

    if($myArray[i] == $myArray[i+1]){
    
        $cont++;
        
        $longest = $cont;
        
        $number = $myArray[i];
    
    } else {
        
        $cont = 1;
    
    }
    
    if($cont > $longest){
    
        $longest = $cont;
        $number = $myArray[i];
    }

}

echo("Longest: " + $longest + "\n" + "Number: " + $number);
```

En la linea 8:

```
if($myArray[i] == $myArray[i+1])
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /box/script.php on line 8
```

Pero no entiendo porque obtengo este error.

Comment: Si la línea `for($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++)` utilizas `$i` por qué luego usas `$myArray[i]`, debes usar `$myArray[$i]`. Es decir todos tus  `i` debes cambiarlos por `$i` porque las variables en PHP se definen anteponiendo el simbolo `$`.

Comment: Has realizado 3 veces la misma pregunta casi en el mismo momento, de distinta forma pero con el mismo objetivo.  ¿Porque no esperas a que te contesten en una antes de volverlo a preguntar?  o bien ¿porque no borras las que ya no necesitas respuesta si es que has avanzado en su resolución? ¿O porque no editas la pregunta si ha sufrido variaciones?  Vas a llenar SOes de preguntas casi iguales y nos vas a volver locos intentando ayudarte cuando quizás ya has avanzado y ya no te hacen falta algunas preguntas.